# PHP countdown with custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, countdowntimer

I want to display the days remaining till the date specified in a custom field inside of wordpress. My custom field is named `bewerbungs_frist`. I'M using this code:

```
<?php $days = ceil((strtotime("<?php the_field('bewerbungsfrist'); ?>") - time())/(60*60*24));
        $s='';
        if ($days!=1) {
             $s='s';
        }
        echo $days. " days "; ?>
```

As a output I get something like -1500 days. That can't be right. Can somebody help me out?

I solved the issue with this code:

```
<p>Bewerbungsfrist: <?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('bewerbungs_frist'));  echo $date->format('d.m.Y');?></p>
noch <?php $days = ceil((strtotime(get_field('bewerbungs_frist')) - time())/(60*60*24));
echo $days. " Tage "; ?>
```

Comment: Which are you using `bewerbungs_frist` or `bewerbungsfrist`? echo `bewerbungs_frist` and echo `time()` and see if the values make any sense

Comment: Using my code the days left are displayed correctly, but I lose my right sidebar of wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening wrong php tags between already opened tags

try this

```
$days = ceil((strtotime(the_field('bewerbungsfrist')) - time())/(60*60*24));
```